# Java Function chaining

Tags: function, java-8

I'm trying to work out why the following code fails to compile:

```
Function<Employee, String> getLastName = (Employee employee) -> {
    return employee.getName().substring(employee.getName().indexOf(" ") + 1);
};

Function<Employee, String> getFirstName = (Employee employee) -> {
    return employee.getName().substring(0, employee.getName().indexOf(" "));
};

Function chained = getFirstName.apply(employees.get(2).andThen(getFirstName.apply(employees.get(2))));
```

Can't all Functions be cahined in java 8?

Comment: is it that only one item can be returned from each function?  In that case chained would be trying to return 2?

Comment: I think I've got the reason: similar to the above, each function chained operates on the previous result, so in this case, it's not sensible code.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly, `andThen` is applied to the result from that `Function`, for example:

```
Function<Employee, String> chained = getFirstName.andThen(x -> x.toUpperCase());
```

`x -> x.toUpperCase()` (or this can be replaced with a method reference `String::toUpperCase`) is applied to the `String` result from `getFirstName` Function.

How do you imagine chaining them? One `Function` returns `String`, so that makes it impossible to chain. *But* you can return both those fields via a single `Function`:

```
 Function<Employee, String[]> bothFunction = (Employee employee) -> {
        String[] both = new String[2];
        both[0] = employee.getName().substring(employee.getName().indexOf(" ") + 1);
        both[1] = employee.getName().substring(0, employee.getName().indexOf(" "));
        return both;
    };
```

Comment: nice explaination.